# C program throws a runtime error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int i,j,k,n,q;
scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&k,&q);
int *m=malloc(5*sizeof(int));
int **a=malloc(20*sizeof(int));
//int a[10][10],m[10];
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
  a[i]=malloc(sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {scanf("%d",&a[0][i]);}
for(i=0;i<q;i++)
   {scanf("%d",&m[i]);}
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
       if(j==(n-1)) a[i+1][0]=a[i][j];
            else
        a[i+1][j+1]=a[i][j];
    }

}
for(i=0;i<q;i++)
printf("%d\n",a[k][m[i]]);
return 0;
}
```

I tried this code in codeblocks but it seems that it doesn't accept any values after I enter the values of `m[]`.
The error is: "matright.exe has stopped working".
The input that i entered was :
3 2 3
1 2 3
0
1
2

Comment: `a[i]=malloc(sizeof(int));` is allocating space for a *single* `int`.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from compiling your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: And please provide suitable input, so we can reproduce your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `malloc`

```
int **a=malloc(20*sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
int **a=malloc(20*sizeof(int*));
```

The third malloc

```
a[i]=malloc(sizeof(int));
```

only allocates memory for one element, yet you follow this with a `n` loop.

**Edit** (from TobySpeight):

Also, the array lengths have been hard coded. Guessing from the loops further down, you should be allocating:

```
int *m = malloc(q * sizeof(int));
int **a = malloc(k * sizeof(int*));
```

with the third one as

```
a[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: @iharob agreed that would be better style and more maintainable.

Comment: Given the loop, then that `20` looks wrong, too: `int **a = malloc(k * sizeof *a);`.  The intention of the rest of the code is so unclear I don't know what to write...

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify your program a bit to make it a self-contained example: it was trying to read from stdin.  So I replaced the `scanf` with calls to this function:

```
int value()
{
    static int n = 0;
    return ++n;
}
```

and I made `n`, `k` and `q` constants:

```
    int n = 4;
    int k = 3;
    int q = 5;
```

Now, I can run Valgrind on it, and the first error is:

> ```
> Invalid write of size 4  
>    at 0x10861D: main (40159824.c:26)  
>  Address 0x51d5134 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd  
>    at 0x4C2ABAF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)  
>    by 0x108609: main (40159824.c:23)
> ```

Line 26 is here:

```
    for (i=0;  i<n;  i++)
        a[0][i] = value();
```

and it's trying to write beyond the end of memory allocated on line 23:

```
       a[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

We only allocated space for one `int`, but we're trying to write `n` of them.  We should have allocated `n` times as much space:

```
       a[i] = malloc(n * sizeof (int));
```

Similar errors occur when allocating `m` and `a`, which are hard-coded to different multiples than `q` and `n` which are used as the limits of iteration over them.

After we fix those errors, we get:

> ```
> Invalid write of size 8
>    at 0x108610: main (40159824.c:23)
>  Address 0x51d50a8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 12 alloc'd
>    at 0x4C2ABAF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>    by 0x1085F4: main (40159824.c:19)
> ```

We now see that we have allocated

```
    int **a = malloc(k*sizeof(int));
```

but `a` is a pointer to `int`, so that should have been `k*sizeof(int*)`.

Instead of having to keep the computation synchronized to the declaration of `a`, we can let the compiler do that, by applying the `sizeof` operator to `*a` directly:

```
    int **a = malloc(k * sizeof *a);
```

Applying this principle throughout gives is this final program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int value()
{
    static int n = 0;
    return ++n;
}


int main()
{
    int n = 4;
    int k = 3;
    int q = 5;
    int i,j;

    int *const m = malloc(q * sizeof *m);
    if (!m)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    int **const a = malloc(k * sizeof *a);
    if (!a)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    for (i=0;  i<k;  i++) {
        a[i] = malloc(n * sizeof *a[i]);
        if (!a[i])
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (i=0;  i<n;  i++)
        a[0][i] = value();

    for (i=0;  i<q;  i++)
        m[i] = value();

    for (i=0;  i<k;  i++) {
        for (j=0;  j<n;  j++) {
            if (j == n-1)
                a[i+1][0]=a[i][j];
            else
                a[i+1][j+1]=a[i][j];
        }

    }

    for (i=0;  i<q;  i++)
        printf("%d\n",a[k][m[i]]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now you don't get any errors until you reference `a[i+1]` on the final pass of the loop (when `i+1` is `k`).  As I don't know the intent of the code (it's hard to pick it up from your single-letter variable names), I don't know whether `a` should be larger, the loop should terminate earlier, or something else entirely, so I leave that for you to fix yourself.

Answer (score -1):

There is no code to accept values after accepting values for `m[]`; the rest of the code is calculation & output.